# A question regarding $\nu_p(2^{p-1} - 1)$ from AoPS

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Here's a question I recently found from browsin AoPS, but couldn't figure out the answer:

> For a prime $p$, let $\nu_p(x)$ denote the highest power of $p$ dividing $x$, for example $\nu_3(8) = 0$, $\nu_2(24)=  3$, $\nu_5(10) = 1$. Is there a positive integer $m$ such that for all primes $p$, we have $$ \nu_p(2^{p-1} - 1) \leq m$$ ?
>    What if $2$ is replaced by some other positive number ?

Comment: Aside : primes for which $m \geq 2$ are called Wieferich primes. There is also a result given there for $m=3$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks for the [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime), I didn't know it before :)  So I guess this question's answer is not known till now (lol)?

Comment: Yes, I  would expect that to be the case. It is a difficult question by the look of it.

Comment: BTW, [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1583116) was the AoPS thread I was talking about.

Comment: That $\nu_p$ is called the $p$-adic norm, and carries very great significance by itself for being an alternate completion of $\mathbb Q$

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean by "itself for being an alternate completion of Q". Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: You say you are in high school, this will then be a little difficult. Actually we "construct" the real numbers from the rational numbers using a technique called completion. Tweaking this technique slightly gives another class of numbers called the $p$-adic numbers, and in that context $\nu_p$ is called a norm. But if you do not understand, you can ignore it, because its definitely not required for elementary problem solving, for example.

Comment: I've experimented with such similar questions and made an essay on my findings. Perhaps you find this inspiring: http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf